# Shutting down a multithreaded application by installing a signal handler

Tags: c++, c++11, signals, signal-handling

In the following code, I create a toy class that has a thread which writes to a queue while the other thread reads from that queue and prints it to `stdout`. Now, in order to cleanly shutdown the system, I setup a handler for `SIGINT`. I am expecting the signal handler to set up the `std::atomic<bool>` variable `stopFlag`, which will lead `threadB` to push a poison pill (sentinel) on to the queue encountering which `threadA` will halt.

```
class TestClass
{
public:

    TestClass();
    ~TestClass();
    void shutDown();

    TestClass(const TestClass&) = delete;
    TestClass& operator=(const TestClass&) = delete;


private:
    void init();
    void postResults();
    std::string getResult();
    void processResults();

    std::atomic<bool> stopFlag;

    std::mutex outQueueMutex;
    std::condition_variable outQueueConditionVariable;
    std::queue<std::string> outQueue;

    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> threadA;
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> threadB;
};

void TestClass::init()
{
    threadA = std::make_unique<std::thread>(&TestClass::processResults, std::ref(*this));
    threadB = std::make_unique<std::thread>(&TestClass::postResults, std::ref(*this));
}

TestClass::TestClass():
    stopFlag(false)
{
    init();
}

TestClass::~TestClass()
{
    threadB->join();
}

void TestClass::postResults()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
        std::string name = "ABCDEF";
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(outQueueMutex);
            outQueue.push(name);
            outQueueConditionVariable.notify_one();
        }
        if(stopFlag)
        {
            /*For shutting down output thread*/
            auto poisonPill = std::string();
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(outQueueMutex);
                outQueue.push(poisonPill);
                outQueueConditionVariable.notify_one();
            }
            threadA->join();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void TestClass::shutDown()
{
    stopFlag = true;
}

std::string TestClass::getResult()
{
    std::string result;
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(outQueueMutex);
        while(outQueue.empty())
        {
            outQueueConditionVariable.wait(lock);
        }
        result= outQueue.front();
        outQueue.pop();
    }
    return result;
}

void TestClass::processResults()
{
    while(true)
    {
        const auto result = getResult();

        if(result.empty())
        {
            break;
        }

        std::cout << result << std::endl;

    }
}

static void sigIntHandler(std::shared_ptr<TestClass> t, int)
{
    t->shutDown();
}
static std::function<void(int)> handler;

int main()
{
    auto testClass = std::make_shared<TestClass>();
    handler = std::bind(sigIntHandler, testClass, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::signal(SIGINT, [](int n){ handler(n);});
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this using gcc 5.2 using the -std=c++14 flag. On hitting Ctrl-C on my CentOS 7 machine, I get the following error,

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Invalid argument
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please help me understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that your `main` function exits immediately destroying global `handler` object and then `testClass`. Then the main thread gets blocked in `TestClass::~TestClass`. The signal handler ends up accessing already destroyed objects, which leads to the undefined behaviour.

The root cause is undefined object ownership due to shared pointers - you do not know what and when ends up destroying your objects.

---

A more general approach is to use another thread to handle all signals and block signals in all other threads. That signal handling thread then can call any functions upon receiving a signal.

You also do not need the smart pointers and function wrappers here at all.

Example:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass();
    ~TestClass();
    void shutDown();

    TestClass(const TestClass&) = delete;
    TestClass& operator=(const TestClass&) = delete;

private:
    void postResults();
    std::string getResult();
    void processResults();


    std::mutex outQueueMutex;
    std::condition_variable outQueueConditionVariable;
    std::queue<std::string> outQueue;
    bool stop = false;

    std::thread threadA;
    std::thread threadB;
};

TestClass::TestClass()
    : threadA(std::thread(&TestClass::processResults, this))
    , threadB(std::thread(&TestClass::postResults, this))
{}

TestClass::~TestClass() {
    threadA.join();
    threadB.join();
}

void TestClass::postResults() {
    while(true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
        std::string name = "ABCDEF";
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(outQueueMutex);
            if(stop)
                return;
            outQueue.push(name);
            outQueueConditionVariable.notify_one();
        }
    }
}

void TestClass::shutDown() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(outQueueMutex);
    stop = true;
    outQueueConditionVariable.notify_one();
}

std::string TestClass::getResult() {
    std::string result;
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(outQueueMutex);
        while(!stop && outQueue.empty())
            outQueueConditionVariable.wait(lock);
        if(stop)
            return result;
        result= outQueue.front();
        outQueue.pop();
    }
    return result;
}

void TestClass::processResults()
{
    while(true) {
        const auto result = getResult();
        if(result.empty())
            break;
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    // Block signals in all threads.
    sigset_t sigset;
    sigfillset(&sigset);
    ::pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, nullptr);

    TestClass testClass;

    std::thread signal_thread([&testClass]() {
        // Unblock signals in this thread only.
        sigset_t sigset;
        sigfillset(&sigset);
        int signo = ::sigwaitinfo(&sigset, nullptr);
        if(-1 == signo)
            std::abort();

        std::cout << "Received signal " << signo << '\n';
        testClass.shutDown();
    });

    signal_thread.join();
}
```

Comment: Am I allowed to do 'std::cout << "Received signal " << signo << '\n';' in the handler?

Comment: @sank You are, this is a normal thread context, not signal handler context.

Comment: In my actual program, I am running child processes in other threads created by by the class. I am noticing abnormal behavior on blocking signals in all threads except the signal handler thread. I am not sure how to proceed. I am using the boost process library btw.

Comment: @sank A good start would be to post another question with code that demonstrates the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

On your platform this signal handler is invoked when a real `SIGINT` signal comes. [The list of functions that can be invoked inside of this signal handler](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html) is rather limited and calling anything else leads to an undefined behavior.

Comment: All I am doing is calling the shutDown method which sets an atomic<bool> to true.

Comment: @sank You are actually calling `lambda::operator ()` then  `std::function::operator()` then `std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(shared_ptr const &)` then `std::shared_ptr::operator->` then `std::shared_ptr::~shared_ptr` (atomic should work because it is probably a non-blocking variant). Also this class has a rather fancy resource ownership pattern which may actually cause a stated exception.

Comment: I understand your point. So how do I set up a signal handler? Should I make stopFlag and shutDown static?

Comment: Please comment on the 'fancy resource ownership pattern' of this class.

Comment: @sank I guess the part about "fancy ownership" has been explained in another answer. As for proper signal handling, I can only recommend making a singleton class that blocks signal handling in main thread, starts its own thread, setups signal handler that sets atomic flag and blocks in `wait`. This class shall provide a single public method to obtain flag state. In destructor this class shall post `SIGINT` into signal waiting thread if flag has not been set yet.